# Can we launch a "link" in iMessage app?

Tags: ios, imessage, imessage-extension

I've got an iMessage app where basically I want to display a button and when pressed, launch another app like Safari or Maps etc.

I've tried:

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){

but "UIApplication.shared" is only available in the main iOS app. Mine is an iMessage only app.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `extensionContext` property inside your `MSMessagesAppViewController` subclass to open URL like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.apple.com/"];
[self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
```

I haven't tested this, but I use this method to launch my iOS application from my iMessage extension app using custom url scheme. I've also used this to launch the AppStore from my iMessage extension.

Update:

Since you said you just want to open Maps, you could try this:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

- (void)openMaps {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.651092f, -117.744250f); // coordinates of your desired location
    MKCoordinateRegion regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, 5000, 5000); // 5000 is the distance in meters
    NSDictionary *options = @{MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:regionSpan.center],
                              MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinateSpan:regionSpan.span]};
    MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinates addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
    [mapItem setName:@"Irvine Spectrum Center"];
    [mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:options];
}
```

Let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It doesn't give me an error which is good but it also doesn't launch into the website. ☹️

Comment: I see. Its probably because your app is an iMessage extension only application. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to launch another app from an extension only app. I will let you know if I ever come across something useful.

Comment: All I want is to launch maps. Or a way to present an address so that users can just tap on it and it opens maps, much like when you send an address via iMessage now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I mean, if you just want to launch maps, it is possible with MapKit I believe. Do you have an address or coordinates that you want to show in the map? And I assume you would want to do this programmatically from you iMessage extension, correct?

Comment: @Bevan I updated the answer to launch Maps. check it out

Comment: Ideally, I would still like to launch a website but this solution is perfect for now! Works great! Thanks so much!

Comment: Yeah it would be nice if we could launch Safari or something as of now, Apple doesn't allow this. You could also use a WKWebView or present an SFSafariViewController from within your iMessage app if you want to open a website.

Comment: Can I? I thought I can only have one screen (viewcontroller) in iMessage. I tried adding another but it was added as a normal ViewController so I didn't go any further. Is it just a matter of adding a new ViewController and assign it a MSMessageViewController class?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to present a modal view controller using the `presentViewController:animated:` method. [Here's a screenshot of my iMessage extension app on the iPhone X simulator](https://imgur.com/a/k9qnZQt). As you can see, I am just presenting an SFSafariViewController like so: `SFSafariViewController *vc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];`